# How do I start service in systemd right after cryptsetup?

Tags: systemd

I have an ArchLinux installation with systemd. I am trying to run a hook immediately after my encrypted data device is mounted in order to put flashcache on top of it. I have scripts that work, however I cannot make them load in right order. Here's what I did:

file: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/flashcache.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=FlashCache
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@cdata.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/flashcache_startup_script

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-mapper-data_cached.device
```

After creating file, I ran `systemctl enable flashcache.service`.

However, on boot it does not start, the dev-mapper-data_cached times out, after which I can get into a root shell and run `flashcache_startup_script` manually.

I examined output of `journalctl -b`, and determined that FlashCache service does not load before timeout occurs.

Another option I tried without success is `Requires=dev-mapper-vg1-data.device`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all sorts of things, mainly using [following resource](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). I am not exactly sure why it worked, but following unit file solved the issue:

```
[Unit]
Description=FlashCache
BindsTo=dev-vg1-data.device
After=dev-vg1-data.device
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/flashcache_startup_script

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```